# Creating a Date object with an offset in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date, object, offset

I'm currently learning how to create applications for Android, but my Java is quite rusty as I'm more of a .NET person.

If in C#, I wanted to create a DateTime object with the value set to todays date plus 5 years, I could use

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);
```

Is there something similar to this in the Java language?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `Calendar` to do the calculation:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
Date date = cal.getTime(); // getTime() returns a Date object
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use JODA time --- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net to create DateTime object.

Use plusYears method to add 5 years to it -- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

```
 DateTime.now().plusYears(5);
```

Comment: I'll bear this in mind for future projects as it looks great, but for now this seems a bit like overkill! :)